# Changing attribute value while parsing with boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Given a string "1, 2, 3, 10, 15", 
the expected output should be 01, 02, 03, 10, 15 - that is, appending "0" to parsed attribute if it's size is not 2. I would easily do that with lambdas as semantic actions, but how to complete the task without using them? I suspect some tricky qi::_val and qi::_1 games should be played here.
What I really wanted would be

```
s = qi::repeat(1,2)[qi::digit] 
[(
        [](auto& parsed_number)
        { 
            return parsed_number.size()==2 ? 
            parsed_number : std::string("0") + parsed_number;
        } 
 ]);
```

but it doesn't work that way

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using V = std::vector<std::string>;

template<typename It, typename Skipper>
struct G: qi::grammar<It, V(), Skipper>
{
    G(): G::base_type(v)
    {
        v = s % ',';
        s = qi::repeat(1,2)[qi::digit];
    }
private:
    qi::rule<It, V(), Skipper> v;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> s;
};


int main()
{
    const std::string s = "1, 2, 3, 10, 15";
    std::string::const_iterator beg(s.begin()), e;
    G<decltype(beg), qi::space_type> g;
    V R;
    bool b = qi::phrase_parse(beg, e, g, qi::space, R);
    if(!b){
        std::cerr << "parsing failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    for(const auto& r: R) std::cout << r << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I assume we are talking spirit v2 here?

Comment: I fear you have a so called XY problem here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377 , because you want to change seem to be valid values because of formatting reasons it seems. Why are you parsing this numbers, are they supposed to be numbers that you later want to output in a 2 digit format? Then delegate that to boost spirit karma, and let numbers be numbers in the mean time (simply ints or something). Otherwise if the strings "01" are only valid use, let me know.

Comment: Sure I could store ints as they are, and then prepend zeros through the cycle , but that would unnecessarily increase complexity by O(N_of_parsed_ints). Furthermore, would like to see an elegant boost-spirit solution.

Comment: No it parsing your ints is O(n) and will still be O(n) after that.

Comment: But still my question remains, do you intend to only find "01" acceptable INPUT or, is  "1" ok, but you want to OUTPUT always as 2 digit numbers? Whats with your stuff BETWEEN your INPUT and OUTPUT. Does it need numbers to be only between 10 and 99 ? Or does it not care, but you want to display it results as at least 2 digit decimal numbers?

Comment: The rule is: keep number with 2 digits as it is and prepend zero otherwise. The key is: I want to know how to change parsed attribute on the fly using boost-spirit. The concrete rule doesn't matter, it just happened to be my current practical need.

Comment: See my answer below. If you don't want to use karma, then you certainly have a bad XY problem, because I see know reasonable use case for you or you have a wrong understanding of computing complexity in theory and practical terms.

Comment: If you would just try to answer my questions it would be much easier: As I said, if you kind of want to translate strings or any value from a to ba or something use a symbol table  ( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/roman_numerals.html ), it it that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
namespace fusion= boost::fusion;

using V = std::vector<std::string>;

template<typename It, typename Skipper>
struct G: qi::grammar<It, V(), Skipper>
{
    G(): G::base_type(v)
    {
        v = s % ',';
        //s = qi::hold[qi::repeat(2)[qi::digit]]|(qi::attr('0') >> qi::digit);
        //s = (&qi::repeat(2)[qi::digit] | qi::attr('0')) >> qi::repeat(1,2)[qi::digit];
        //s = qi::as_string[qi::repeat(1,2)[qi::digit]] [qi::_val = phx::if_else(phx::size(qi::_1)==2,qi::_1,phx::val('0')+qi::_1)]; 
        s = qi::as_string[qi::repeat(1,2)[qi::digit]]
[(
        [](auto& parsed_number, auto& ctx)
        { 
            fusion::at_c<0>(ctx.attributes) = parsed_number.size()==2 ? 
            parsed_number : '0' + parsed_number;
        } 
 )]; 
    }
private:
    qi::rule<It, V(), Skipper> v;
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> s;
};


int main()
{
    const std::string s = "1, 2, 3, 10, 15";
    std::string::const_iterator beg(s.begin()), e;
    G<decltype(beg), qi::space_type> g;
    V R;
    bool b = qi::phrase_parse(beg, e, g, qi::space, R);
    if(!b){
        std::cerr << "parsing failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    for(const auto& r: R) std::cout << r << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <iterator>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

using SNT = long int;
using V = std::vector<SNT>;

template<typename It, typename Skipper>
struct G: qi::grammar<It, V(), Skipper>
{
    G(): G::base_type(v)
    {
        v = s % ',';
        s = qi::int_parser<SNT>(); /*Change to  qi::int_parser<SNT,10,2> if you also only
 * want to accept at least 2 digit decimals*/
    }
private:
    qi::rule<It, V(), Skipper> v;
    qi::rule<It, SNT(), Skipper> s;
};

template<typename OutputIterator>
struct GG : karma::grammar<OutputIterator, V()> {
    GG() : GG::base_type(start) {
        start = karma::right_align(2,'0')[karma::int_generator<SNT>()] % '\n';

    }
    karma::rule<OutputIterator, V()> start;
};


int main()
{
    const std::string s = "1, 2, 3, 10, 15";
    std::string::const_iterator beg(s.begin()), e;
    G<decltype(beg), qi::space_type> g;
    V R;
    bool b = qi::phrase_parse(beg, e, g, qi::space, R);
    if(!b){
        std::cerr << "parsing failed\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for(const auto& r: R) std::cout << r << '\n';

    std::string o{};
    V O;
    GG<std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>> gg;
    b = karma::generate(std::back_inserter(o), gg, R);
    if (!b)
        throw std::runtime_error{"Generation failed"};

    std::cout << o;
}
```

Comment: using qi::int_parser<SNT,10,2>() makes parsing failed.

Comment: Of course since it would then expect s to be "01, 02, 03, 10, 15"